# A hint to the differential equation $xy'' + y' + \dfrac{1}{4\sqrt x}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am a bit unsure about how one would tackle this differential equation; I ran the problem in Maple and it gives a nice solution.

I am quite new to differential equations of this "sort" so I am asking for some kind of hint how one would approach a solution? Very appreciated.

Comment: Here is a hint. Set $w=y'$

Comment: I'd say you just integrate, taking into account that $x\,y''+y'$ is the derivative of $x\,y'$.

Comment: Hint: $xy'' + y' = (xy')'$. Set $w = xy'$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways we could approach this problem. Specific to this problem, we can rearrange the equation and integrate directly

$$xy''+y'=(xy')' = -\frac{1}{4\sqrt{x}} \implies xy' = -\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}+C_1$$

being careful about adding a constant each time we integrate. Assuming $x>0$ we can then divide by $x$ and integrate again

$$y' = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+\frac{C_1}{x} \implies y = -\sqrt{x}+C_1\log x +C_2$$

On the other hand, the systematic approach to this problem would be to solve for the homogeneous solution then the particular. The equation

$$xy''+y' = 0 \implies x^2y''+xy'+0\cdot y=0$$

is a Cauchy-Euler equation with the known ansatz $y=x^r$

$$r(r-1)x^r+rx^r+0\cdot x^r= (r^2)x^r = 0$$

The characteristic polynomial has a repeated root at $r=0$, meaning the homogeneous solutions are $1$ and $\log x \cdot 1$. The $\log x$ is tacked on to the solution for the same reason $xe^x$ is the repeated root solution for a constant coefficient differential equation, it is the "eigenvalue" equation for a generalized eigenvector i.e. if I have a generalized eigenvector such that

$$Av^{(2)} = \lambda v^{(2)} + v^{(1)}$$

where $v^{(1)}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue of $\lambda$, then we have that

$$f(A)v^{(2)} = f(\lambda)v^{(2)}+f'(\lambda)v^{(1)}$$

In other words the repeated root solution in our case would be (with eigenvalue $r=0$)

$$C_1x^r + \frac{d}{dr}(x^r)C_2 = C_1x^r + C_2 \log x x^r = C_1 + C_2\log x$$

From here you can guess that the particular solution is of the form $A\sqrt{x}$ and use undetermined coefficients.

Comment: Equation 3 is missing a factor $x$ in the left side, or you have to make it two equivalent equations.